# Cannot find qryname14411 key in structure

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I have an error that seems to be associated with `<cfscript>` db operation

```
// traffic tracking
myQry = new Query();
myQry.setSQL("INSERT INTO   dbo.Traffic (Circuit, Fuseaction, IP_hash) VALUES   (:circuit, :fuseaction, :ip_hash)");
myQry.addParam(name="circuit",      value="#listfirst(rc.fuseaction, '.')#",    cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR");
myQry.addParam(name="fuseaction",   value="#listlast(rc.fuseaction, '.')#",     cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR");
myQry.addParam(name="ip_hash",      value="#cgi.remote_addr#",                  cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR");    
myQry.execute();
```

The really strange thing is, it looks like the operation completed. What kind of a error is this?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer:** It's probably a scoping issue. Try:

```
var myQry = new Query();
```

**Long-winded waffley answer:**

I'd call it an Adobe-developers-being-useless kind of error.

If you look at line 460 of that file, you'll see the error is due to a failure of StructFind to find the query name in the variables scope, and the reason it's appearing in debug input is because there's a try/catch with type any surrounding it. The same functionality could be achieved *without* causing/catching an error by replacing the try/catch with `<cfif StructKeyExists(variables,tagAttributes['name']) >` which is basic CFML knowledge, and certainly something a developer of the CF product should know!

The same code still exists in the CF10 version of base.cfc, so you may or not feel like submitting it as a bug in Adobe's [CF bugbase](https://bugbase.adobe.com) - though it's unlikely they'll fix it for CF9 (and uncertain whether they'll feel CF10 is worth the effort either).

However, that would only be side-stepping the issue of the variable not existing, not addressing the real issue of *why* it doesn't actually exist. Given that the debug info shows the query is successfully executing, and the query code is basically right above that line (starts at line 442), it shouldn't be a repeated/common error, but **it may be due to your `myQry` variable not being scoped**, and thus it could be colliding with another variable also called myQry (or even the same var from a separate call to the function) which is happening between the execution of the `new Query()` and `.execute()` lines, and thus causing the original query to not be there when the StructFind looks for it.

The solution is to **put the keyword `var` before the first use of `myQry`** which will place it in the local scope for that function - something that should be done for all variables that are only for use within an instance of a function, (otherwise they are placed in the variables scope of the component/request that the function exists within).

Comment: I specify the local scope and I'm getting the same error.  I'd like to continue to refer to variables as local.svc instead of "var svc", but at least now I know why I'm getting the warning message!

Comment: It looks like I have to go back and put var local = {} into all my functions.