# Data Insert Issue from Coldfusion to Oracle

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, oracle11g, coldfusion-9

I am reading a text file and have created a string as below to insert data into the Database (Oracle 11g).

```
INSERT ALL
INTO INDEX_DATA (DATETIME, COMMODITY, IDX, IDX_VALUE, VCDATE) VALUES ('15-May-2014', 'FN1 Comdty', 'PX_LA', 44.75, SYSDATE)
INTO INDEX_DATA (DATETIME, COMMODITY, IDX, IDX_VALUE, VCDATE) VALUES ('15-May-2014', 'FN1 Comdty', 'PX_H', 45.1, SYSDATE)
INTO INDEX_DATA (DATETIME, COMMODITY, IDX, IDX_VALUE, VCDATE) VALUES ('15-May-2014', 'FN1 Comdty', 'PX_L', 44.47, SYSDATE)
and so on ...7000 rows
select * from dual
```

The coldfusion page is timing out while inserting the above query at once. The query works fine for 100 records.

I'm really not sure if this is an Oracle or Coldfusion limitation since Toad is also not responding for the same query.

In case its a coldfusion issue, please advise if there is an alternate way of inserting the data than hitting the database for each insert statement.

Edit 1: I can use a flag and do an insert every `n` rows, if no other solution exists.

Comment: Why not define an external table using the text file as input? Generating this kind of SQL is not a very nice solution, it fills the shared pool with garbage causing many extra parsing and slowing down the whole database. What wait events does the session have during the insert? (look in v$session)

Comment: If you have access to Oracle's bulk loader, that would be a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend 2 actions.  First set the request time out to override your default settings.  Second, Load up your insert statements into an array, loop over them, and commit at regular intervals.  Here is a simple example that demonstrates the behavior. Expected results are that it would insert 10 letters into the tmp table before an error on the 12th record.  The first 10 would be committed.

```
<cfsetting requesttimeout="3600"><!--- This is the number of seconds that before coldfusion will timeout your request.  Change it to an appropriate value for your situation.  It can't override timeouts on the database side --->
<cfscript>
    sqlStatements=[
"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('a')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('b')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('c')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('d')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('e')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('f')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('g')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('h')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('i')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('j')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('k')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('l')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('m')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('n')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('o')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('p')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('q')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('r')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('s')"
,"INSERT INTO tmp (letter) values ('t')"
];
commitafter="5";
throwafter="12";
qryInsert= new Query();
qryInsert.setDatasource("yourdatasourcename");
transaction{
    statementCount=0;
for (sqlStatement in sqlStatements){
        statementCount=statementCount+1;
        qryInsert.setSQL(sqlStatement);
        qryInsert.execute();
        if (statementCount eq throwafter) {
            throw (message="manual throw for testing");
        }
        if (statementCount MOD commitafter eq 0){
            transaction action="commit";
        }
    }
    transaction action="commit";
}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: You might find that you don't have to increase the timeout.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @Gerry. The data is committed in a batch now. Although, I'm getting this weird exception `Expression Exception - in C:\ColdFusion9\CustomTags\com\adobe\coldfusion\base.cfc : line 375
Cannot find qrynameXXXX key in structure.` for each of the inserted statement in the coldfusion page debug. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a guess without testing, but try this: qryInsert.setName("myName");  You can add an iterator to it to make each name distinct ike this  qryInsert.setName("myName" & i); Assuming these are just warnings and not stopping your code. I'm running CF10 also so that might be a minor difference

Comment: Yes @GerryGurevich, just the warnings; the data is inserting as expected. The issue is similar to the one in the link below but the answer doesn't solve the issue; neither the setName worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349122/cannot-find-qryname14411-key-in-structure